# C# parallel foreach does not give expected speedup

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am trying to find out why parallel foreach does not give the expected speedup on a machine with 32 physical cores and 64 logical cores with a simple test computation.

```
... 
var parameters = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    parameters.Add(i.ToString());
    if (Scenario.UsesParallelForEach)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(parameters, parameter => {
            FireOnParameterComputed(this, parameter, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "started");
            var lc = new LongComputation();
            lc.Compute();
            FireOnParameterComputed(this, parameter, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "stopped");
        });
    } 
    else
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            FireOnParameterComputed(this, parameter, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "started");
            var lc = new LongComputation();
            lc.Compute();
            FireOnParameterComputed(this, parameter, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "stopped");
        }
    }
}
...

class LongComputation
{
    public void Compute()
    {
        var s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 40000; i++)
        {
            s = s + i.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The Compute function takes about 5 seconds to complete. My assumption was, that with the parallel foreach loop each additional iteration creates a parallel thread running on one of the cores and taking as much as it would take to compute the Compute function only once. So, if I run the loop twice, then with the sequential foreach, it would take 10 seconds, with the parallel foreach only 5 seconds (assuming 2 cores are available). The speedup would be 2. If I run the loop three times, then with the sequential foreach, it would take 15 seconds, but again with the parallel foreach only 5 seconds. The speedup would be 3, then 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. However, what I observe is a constant speedup of 1.3.

[Sequential vs parallel foreach. X-axis: number of sequential/parallel execution of the computation. Y-axis: time in seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0DqG.png)

[Speedup, time of the sequential foreach divided by parallel foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/778lR.png)

The event fired in FireOnParameterComputed is intended to be used in a GUI  progress bar to show the progress. In the progress bar it can be clearly see, that for each iteration, a new thread is created.

My question is, why don't I see the expected speedup or at least close to the expected speedup?

Comment: You aren't parallelizing anything in this code. You are running the *same* method, multiple times in parallel. If `Compute` takes 5 seconds, running it 4 times in parallel on a quad machine will still take 5 seconds. If you didn't use `Parallel.Foreach` though it would take 20'

Comment: Of course, if you run this in a dual core machine, trying to run more than two instances at the same time won't improve performance. After all, one core can run only one thread at a time

Comment: Concatenating strings like this causes big memory copies, these strings are like half a megabyte. The performance of that can be stretched a bit with multiple cores, but nowhere near as well as actual computations

Comment: @harold The Compute code is not relevant. The real computations are complex simulations, that take several seconds to minutes to complete and use a considerable amount of memory (several hundred megabytes). I deliberately chose the inefficient way of concatenating strings to create a simple loop which requires a non trivial amount of computation. The server I am running this on has 128GB main memory.

Comment: @Hubert for the real task as well as this fake one, it is still the case that if it leans too much on a shared resource such as LLC bandwidth (or memory bandwidth), it will not scale well to many cores.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is just some trivial test code that shows my problem. The real code involves a simulation that computes different results in each of its runs. What I would like to do is to give each simulation to one core and have it compute there. If that is possible, then the time to run n simulations (n <= number of available cores) should be the same as running the simulation once (in my case, all the simulations will take the same time to compute regardless of the result). My experiment with a trivial compute function shows, that this is not the case.

Comment: For example if I try simpler test code [like this](https://gist.github.com/IJzerbaard/db056edd49b70f8bf06bcba5a1921274), then the overhead for the parallelism is small and it scales well to multiple cores (I did not use a very aggressive number here since I use a quadcore CPU)

Comment: I have noticed in debug mode that the parallel for each loop will run extremely slow, sometimes slower than a regular ForEach loop. Try building it in release mode and running the .exe and see if that will speed up the process.

Comment: @pg1988 We don't develop on the compute server. Instead we create a release version and install it on the computer server. So the performance tests were not run using the debug mode

Comment: @Hubert the code doesn't show any problem, unless it's a misunderstanding of what Parallel.ForEach does. `Parallel.For/ForEach` makes sense *inside* `Compute`. `Compute` should contain a `Parallel.For/ForEach` instead of a loop. That would *partition* the input data into as many partitions as there are cores (roughly) and use *one* task to process each partition at full speed. For 4 cores that could result in 400% improvement. That's not what the questions code does though, it's almost as if it's trying to use `Parallel.ForEach` like `Task.Run` to run multiple `Compute` instances concurrently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What is the difference between a normal foreach loop and then use Task.Run to run the Compute code instead of using the Parallel.ForEach loop? Shouldn't both behave the same?

Comment: @harold Thanks for your input. Indeed, the different threads fight for the access to main memory which slows down everything. I have changed the Compute code so that it does not use a lot of memory, and now I get the expected speedup.

Comment: I suppose you could use a thread sleep or task.delay to simulate a long running function.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks aren't threads.

Sometimes starting a task will cause a thread to be created, but not always. Creating and managing threads consumes time and system resources. When a task only takes a short amount of time, even though it's counter-intuitive, the single-threaded model is often faster.

The CLR knows this and tries to make its best judgment on how to execute the task based on a number of factors including any hints that you've passed to it.

For Parallel.ForEach, if you're certain that you want multiple threads to be spawned, try passing in ParallelOptions.

```
Parallel.ForEach(parameters, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }, parameter => {});
```

Comment: We have instrumented our code such that it shows if each computation runs in a new thread or not. In the above examples all computations run in their own threads on the compute server.

Comment: We are already using MaxDegreeOfParallelism in a different part of the code. As far as I have observed (and read) is that MaxDegreeOfParallelism can only be used to restrict the number of tasks the OS chooses to run in their own thread, but not to increase that number.